# How do you get RowCount of GridViews ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get the ObjectDataSource RowCount i've tried this

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = (System.Data.DataTable)gview.DataSource
dt.Rows.Count
```

But i get object not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Is `gview.DataSource` `null`?

Comment: In what page event are you trying to retrieve the count?  The DataSource items are really only available in the way you are trying to retrieve information during data binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = (System.Data.DataTable)gview.DataSource;
int Total=dt.Rows.Count;
```